# Detect whether radio button is disabled or enabled

Tags: jquery, asp.net, radio-button, isenabled

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdStatus" onclick="javacript:display();" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical">
<asp:ListItem Text="Temporary Waiver" Value="T" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>    
<asp:ListItem Text="Never Expires" Value="P"></asp:ListItem>    
<asp:ListItem Text="Expires after the close of:" Value="W"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

function display()
{
    if(radiobuton is enabled)
          //code here
     else
          //code here
}
```

Please suggest some idea to detect hoe to check radiobutton is disable o enable

Comment: can you share the generated html instead of asp code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use jQuery to attach to the click event of the radio button list and then use the jQuery `:enabled` selector, like this:

```
$('#rdStatus').click(function () {
    if($(this).is(':enabled')) { 
        // Do enabled radio button code here 
    }
    else {
        // Do disabled radio button code here
    }
});
```

Now you can remove the `onclick` attribute of your radio button list markup, because jQuery is going to find the radio button list (`rdStatus`) and wire up the click event to it for you.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdStatus" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical">
```

Comment: onclick="javacript:display();" here what modification i have to made

Comment: @Blossom - updated answer to use jQuery event handler instead of markup using `onclick` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdStatus"  runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical">
<asp:ListItem Text="Temporary Waiver" Value="T" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>    
<asp:ListItem Text="Never Expires" Value="P"></asp:ListItem>    
<asp:ListItem Text="Expires after the close of:" Value="W"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

$("#<%=rdStatus.ClientID%>").click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('enabled'))
    {
        $(this).removeattr('enabled');
        $(this).attr('disabled',true);
    }
    else
    {
    }
});
```